# How do you use Parsley framework in Flex Hero 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, parsley

I was wondering if Parsley framework is compatible for Flex Hero Mobile 4.5? I seem to get a warning saying it's not compatible.
Thanks guys

Comment: The error I am getting is 
Design mode could not load spicelib-flex-2.3.2.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex 4.5 and Parsley 2.3 don't play nicely together.  Grab [2.4M2 from the website](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/download.php) and all should be fine.

See [this forum post](http://www.spicefactory.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=5133&sid=a2a1e34795dab05dd8e8f5123df75af7) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the code?  OR a SWC you downloaded from a web site?  I assume the latter.

Download the code and recompile it against the Flex 4.5 SDK.  There are often issues when using a SWC that is compiled against a different version of the SDK than your main application.

Comment: right the latter but compiling it i get a few errors as well. just wanted to confirm someone else has done it successfully before first.

Comment: Seems like you need to update your question w/ the errors in question and then we can see about helping you solve those.